# Missing files/folders in Unity iOS build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build, editor

I'm trying to embed a Unity project into a Swift/XCode project, and was having trouble getting the window to appear. I realized none of the assets from the editor were in the build folder, and when I looked further, it seemed to be the "default" build folder, as if I created an empty project and saved it. I've changed various settings in Build Settings as well as Player Settings, to no avail. I tried Build and Run, to no avail. My editor is up-to-date and so is XCode. The project works fine in the editor (it's not large at all, just a golf club with a motion script), but all of that seems to disappear when I build the project and view it in XCode alongside the native Swift project.

Edit: I just built the project for Windows/MacOS/Linux, and it gave me a file I could run and it was exactly what I had in the editor. However, when I switch back to iOS, the corresponding build folder again does not include any assets, it's basically an empty build folder. I have looked at similar stack overflow posts, and none of the solutions worked for me. I'm at a loss

Edit 2: When I build the iOS project, and run the .xcodeproj, it successfully loads the exact scene I have in the editor. So, the files must be there somewhere, and it must somehow be saving correctly. But the Assets folder is not where it should be, and I can't move forward with my Swift/Unity development without having access to the folders and files that are supposed to be included in a Unity iOS build. For instance, the iOS build I get doesn't include either of the NativeCallProxy files.

Comment: In your .xcodeproj under Data are your assets? Try to narrow it more down. Is the issue that Unity3D doesnt export your assets to xcode or is xcode not deploying them to your device?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas to debug this issue:

- **Examine the build logs** in Unity to see if there are any errors or warnings related to the missing files or folders. You can find the build logs in the **Unity Console**.
- **Make sure the file paths** used in your code **are correct** and that they match the paths of the files in your project. You can use `Application.dataPath` or `Application.streamingAssetsPath` to reference files in your project.
- After building your Unity project for iOS, **open the generated Xcode project** and **inspect the file structure** (especally the `Data` folder) to ensure that the missing files or folders are present.
- Use **Xcode's debugging tools** when you run the app on the device. Check for any runtime errors or issues related to file access.